# How to export a Viber conversation on iOS?

Tags: ios, data-transfer

I can't find such an option in Settings for iOS or the app itself.

Is there a way to export a Viber conversation on iOS?

Comment: Device?  Version of iOS?

Comment: @Allan I believe it doesn't really matter, because Viber app is the same across any iOS device and on any iOS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way how to export Viber chats on iOS (taken from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/viber/comments/10q0vhx/viber_chat_to_pdf_or_document/))

1. Type `viber://more/email_message_history_on` link somewhere on your device. For example, create a note with it.
2. Tap on that link.
3. It will open Viber app settings with a hidden setting added: "Email Message History".
4. Press it and send all your messages to your email address.
5. Done!